# How to add multiple attributes to dropdown list at the time of population

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, combobox

i could solved it just by for loops this way

for loop iterate in datasource and rest of the code as follows

```
ListItem test  = new ListItem { Text = srText, Value = srValue}
test.Attributes.Add("data-imagesrc", "xxx");
test.Attributes.Add("data-description", "xxx");
dropListUserImages.Items.Add(test);
```

may be there could be error in code because i have composed the above code in notepad. i guess my above code approach will solve my problem but just wondering that can i do the same with LINQ.

here i am giving a sample code which populating dropdown by LINQ but not sure that below code will allow us to add multiple attribute value coming from db?
below sample code taken from `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710841/making-drop-down-list-in-asp-net-by-foreach-loop`

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
    .Select(i => new { Text= i.ToString(), Value=i.ToString() });
test.DataSource = source;
test.DataTextField = "Text";
test.DataValueField = "Value";
test.DataBind();
```

looking for guidance to achieve the same with LINQ if possible. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the  `DataSource` + `DataBind` approach if you want to add custom attributes. But why don't you use a simple loop?

```
var source = db.TableName.Take(1000) // if you only want 1000
    .Select(sr => new { 
        srText   = sr.srText, 
        srValue  = sr.srValue,
        imagesrc = "xxx",    // change
        description = "xxx"  // change
    });

foreach(var x in source)
{
    ListItem test  = new ListItem { Text = x.srText, Value = x.srValue };
    test.Attributes.Add("data-imagesrc", x.imagesrc);
    test.Attributes.Add("data-description", x.description);
    dropListUserImages.Items.Add(test);
}
```

Comment: yes that i did but just like to know is it possible or not?

Comment: what ur first code will do for `imagesrc = "xxx", description = "xxx"` ?

Comment: @Mou: no, afaik not. But even `DataBind` loops the `DataSource`. So this is as efficient as the `DataBind` approach. I have used `imagesrc = "xxx"` since that is what _you_ have used. You haven't mentioned what you want to select.

Comment: does this line `imagesrc = "xxx", description = "xxx"` ? add any attribute to dropdown called imagesrc & description ??